# How do I call data I included in a python package?

Tags: python

I have a python package with this file structure:

```
package
    - bin
        clean_spam_ratings.py
    - spam_module
        - data
            spam_ratings.csv
        __init__.py
        spam_ratings_functions.py
```

Contents of clean_spam_ratings.py:

```
import spam_module
with open(path_to_spam_ratings_csv, 'r') as fin:
    spam_module.spam_ratings_functions(fin)
```

What should I set `path_to_spam_ratings_csv` to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a module, then you can get the absolute path for the directory that contains that module via:

```
os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

You can use then that to construct the path to your `csv` file.  For example, if you are in `spam_ratings_functions.py`, use:

```
path_to_spam_ratings_csv = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", "data", "spam_ratings.csv")
```